# How to generate a class with a typealias parameter via kotlinpoet

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I want to generate a kotlin class definition with typealias.

```
typealias MyAlias = BigDecimal
class TemplateState(var test: MyAlias) {
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the [documentation](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet#type-aliases):

```
//create a TypeAlias and store it to use the name later
val typeAlias = TypeAliasSpec.builder("MyAlias", BigDecimal::class).build()
val type = TypeSpec.classBuilder("TemplateState").primaryConstructor(
    FunSpec.constructorBuilder().addParameter(
        //You can use the ClassName class to get the typeAlias type
        ParameterSpec.builder("test", ClassName("", typeAlias.name)).build()
    )
).build()
FileSpec.builder("com.example", "HelloWorld")
    .addTypeAlias(typeAlias)
    .addType(type)
    .build()
```

Comment: nope, this will generate a typealias itself. But I need a class definition with typealias like: class TemplateState(var test: MyAlias)

Comment: @Sahka I added the full implementation. I dont have an IDE so please excuse the typos.

Comment: @NicoHaase yeah sure.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari still nope...  this is a result what your code produces


package com.example

import java.math.BigDecimal

typealias MyAlias = BigDecimal

class TemplateState(
  test: BigDecimal
)
In short: typeAlias.type just returns original type...

Comment: Can you check this one? @Sahka

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Excellen!! It works!

package com.example

import MyAlias
import java.math.BigDecimal

typealias MyAlias = BigDecimal

class TemplateState(
  test: MyAlias
)


Thank, @SaeedEntezari!

Answer (score 0):

KotlinPoet doesn't really care whether a `ClassName` represents a `typealias` or a real type. In your case, `ClassName("", "MyAlias")` (assuming `MyAlias` is declared in the default package) is enough to use as the type of the constructor parameter. Of course you'd need to generate the `typealias` separately to ensure the generated code compiles.